# How can I close a custom form and force behavior afterwards?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, customization, sharepoint-workflow

I have been struggling with a problem for some time now, and am hoping that someone may shed some light on some possible solutions.

I currently have a custom creation form for items on a SharePoint 2010 list.  I need to figure out a way to fully save the item and close the form and THEN either fire off a Nintex Workflow or have some custom functionality to create an item in another list with some fields from the current item.

The current trouble is that the workflow being fired upon item creation on this list MUST fire itself off before the form fully closes.  This means that, if the server is taking a lot of time to fire up the workflow, my form simply hangs there idly for quite some time before closing.

**SHORT VERSION:**  I need to be able to save item and close form, then fire off some functionality which will create an item on a separate list with this item's information.

Has anyone figured out a way around this?  I am aware of how to create items in lists using JavaScript rather than Nintex as well, if that helps.  I don't need to use workflow, if there is another way to go about this.  Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I believe Nintex 2010 workflows on item creation are triggered by asynchronous event handler. Meaning it fires after your custom Creation page has finished saving the item. I may be wrong on this, I will get the confirmation from Nintex later.

You can always write up an asynchronous event handler to kick off your custom action or your Nintex workflow instead of relying on firing up the workflow automatically. In either case it will be run after your item is created.

This approach requires coding though. If you are not a developer. Then maybe you need to focus on why your creation form takes so long to close. Does it try to bring up the list view after saving the item?

Comment: I apologize for being so slow to respond -- there has been a lot going on. I am a developer, though I am rather new. Thank you very much for your response, this may give me some things to research more in-depth.  If it's not too much to ask, could you elaborate a bit more on 'asynchronous event handlers'?  Is that something I could create with JavaScript on the item creation form itself, or does it need to run separately?  Thank you very much for your response!!!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to add custom event on your SharePoint List is to use an event receiver.

The event ItemAdding while be raised when new item will be added. You'll be able to interact with the other list from this.

[First step with visual studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg252010%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

[All event receivers for SharePoint 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff408183%28v=office.14%29.aspx)